# Dúvidas sobre um problema de algoritmo

Tags: algoritmo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não entendi o que a questão pede para fazer, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: talvez o que você não tenha entendi é que p símbolo % retorna o resto da divisão ex. 5%100 = 5.

Comment: O operador \ é o operador de divisão inteira (150/100 dá 1,5 e 150/100 dá 1). O operador % é o operador resto da divisão (ou módulo) (13%10 dá 3). Suponha que você informe o número 1234, o resultado seria: d: 1, a: 2, b: 3, c: 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O algoritmo essencialmente vai separar os dígitos do número que você entrou e exibir na tela. Como o tipo é inteiro, então ele irá truncar o valor das expressões. Exemplo: x = 5423

- x/1000 -> 5
- (x/100)%10 -> 4
- (x%100)/10 -> 2
- (x%10)%10 -> 3

Answer (score 1):

Fala, Arashi!
Então, o exercício solicita que você escreva o retorno das 4 operações, concatenados com o texto "Resultado:" no início do texto.
Caso você tenha tido dúvida nas operações. O operador "\" representa a divisão inteira, então é uma divisão que pega só a parte inteira da resposta, descartando o que vem após a vírgula. E o operador "%" faz exatamente o contrário, ele faz a divisão mas fica com tudo que está após a vírgula.